# How do we construct the coslice category $C / \bf{C}$ given $\textbf{C}/C$ and prove that the two are equal?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, constructive-mathematics

The coslice category $C/\bf{C}$ under an object $C \in \bf{C}$ has as objects arrows $f$ in $\bf{C}$ such that $\textbf{dom}(f) = C$ and as arrows, arrows $a: f \to g$ which are arrows $a$ in $ \bf{C}$ such that $af = g$.

So I want to construct this coslice category from the slice category $\textbf{C}/C$ and the $\textbf{op}$ operator (opposite or "dual" categories).

$\textbf{C}/C$ is the same thing as $C/\bf{C}$ except in the definition $\textbf{cod}(f) = C$ and $f = ga$.

So my guess is that $\textbf{C}^{\text{op}}/C = C/\textbf{C}$ since $(\textbf{C}/C)^{\text{op}}$ would first discard some arrows, namely those strictly coming from $C$ (not going *to*).

But intuitively we need take the $\textbf{op}$ of the whole thing: $(\textbf{C}^{\text{op}}/C)^{\text{op}}$ since otherwise all of our objects would be arrows pointing at $C$ not under $C$.

Therefore that is my final guess.  Now what would suffice as a proof that the two are equal: $(\textbf{C}^{\text{op}}/C)^{\text{op}} = C/\bf{C}$?

Comment: What would suffice is a demonstration that they have the same objects and the same arrows, as is indeed the case.

Comment: @KevinCarlson K, working on a proof now.  But why do these easy proofs always seem difficult to me in category theory?  Is there an easy way to view things so that these proofs become more fluid?

Comment: @FruitfulApproach: One way to do this is to exhibit an isomorphism between them. This will be a functor defined in a pretty obvious way.

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido why go for isomorphism when there is equality?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, because it's not clear what aspect you're having trouble with. I'll include an example proof below.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I could prove this to myself, but I am wondering what you think mathematicians in general would call a proof.  I am actually interested in a more visual proof, so if you could do this using commuting triangles, it would be fantastic.  Why waste this opportunity in math to look at things visually?  I.e. not strictly as a 1-D sequence of algebraic symbols?

Comment: Oh, sure, you could certainly just draw the triangles I wrote as equations. There's no difference, as far as what counts as a proof, and definitely that's the way I actually visualize the proof.

Comment: This is quite late but you can't usually hope for equality (it is a technical detail of no relevance). Recall that when a morphism a in C appears as a morphism in C/c, it may appear multiple times in the guise of the same internal action but as different arrows with different domains and codomains. The same is the case with constructing the coslice category. But the exact encoding / construction of the arrows (e.g. as a tuple of the original function, the new domain and the new codomain) is usually left unspecified, so the arrows in the isomorphism may be different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects of $(\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/C)^{\mathrm{op}}$ are by definition the morphisms $D\to C$ in $\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$, which are by definition the morphisms $C\to D$ in $\mathbf{C}$, that is, the objects of  $C/\mathbf{C}$.

A morphism $(f:D\to C)\to (g:E\to C)$ in the same category is by definition a morphism $a:g\to f$ in $\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}/C$, that is, a commutative triangle $f\circ a=g$ in $\mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$. Such triangles are by definition the triangles $a\circ f=g$ in $\mathbf{C}$, that is, the morphisms $f\to g$ in $C/\mathbf{C}$.